# How to store a JSON Variable with AngularJS ngStorage to $sessionStorage

Tags: angularjs, sessionstorage, ng-storage

I have the following variable which is easily transformed to a JSON-String:

```
var data = {
    ball: {
        colour: "",
        size: "",
        price: ""
    },
    toys: []
}
```

In my Controller I want add this variable to the scope like:

```
$scope.data = angular.copy(data)
```

Then I want it to store on the $sessionStorage like:

```
$sessionStorage.data = angular.toJson($scope.data);
```

After the page refresh the `$scope.data` is empty again. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it not possible with $sessionStorage? If no why and what is the difference to $localStorage? @SaEChowdary

Comment: After refresh your data is in `$sessionStorage.cv`, not `$scope.data`. That last line of code merely serializes the data into sessionStorage. You need code that will deserialize it out of sessionStorage when it is not present. Something like `$scope.data = $scope.data || $sessionStorage.cv`.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise? Is it even possible to store an array rather than a normal variable? @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: I just saw that you were storing something in $sessionStorage, but never pulling it out, which just logically wouldn't work. I've not worked with ngStorage, so I'm not exactly sure how the serialization it works. That's why I wrote it as a comment and not an answer :). The way I figure this stuff out is to try it and see what happens. If it doesn't work, try something else. Also, [the documentation for ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) includes a number of examples.

Comment: Yeah I have had a look at this. Did not help me that much. @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: No the data variable is defined outside of the controller since it is only a "data-structure". I tried your solution. Did not work. @nabin

Comment: I am doing something like this now: 
`$scope.$storage = $sessionStorage;`
`$scope.cv = angular.copy(cv) || $scope.$storage.cv;`

And in another function I do:
`$scope.$storage.cv = $scope.cv;`
It sets the $scope.$storage.cv but it does not assign it to `$scope,.cv`
@nabin

Comment: Can you make this expression easier for me? `$scope.cv = angular.copy(cv) || $scope.$storage.cv;`
What I need is: If $storage.cv as in the cv variable is not null it has to be assigned to `$scope.cv` @nabin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how my code works:

```
    $scope.$storage = $sessionStorage;

    if (typeof $scope.$storage.data !== 'undefined') {
        $scope.data = $scope.$storage.data;
    } else {
        $scope.data = angular.copy(data);
        $scope.$storage.data = $scope.data;
    }
```

A shorter solution would be:

```
    $scope.cv = $scope.$storage.cv || angular.copy(cv);
    $scope.$storage.cv = $scope.cv;
```

Comment: `$scope.cv = $scope.$storage.cv ||  angular.copy(cv);`

Comment: This does not work! You still need: `$scope.$storage.data = $scope.data;` for the else!